# Bulk Processing with Java Stream

Tags: java, spring, java-stream

I have a definition of a Stream such as: "They are wrappers around a data source, allowing us to operate with that data source and making bulk processing convenient and fast. "

Can someone give an example and just a basic explanation of how it works such that Stream makes "bulk processing convenient and fast"?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no need to use Streams to do that.

Comment: So you are saying - use of stream is not more efficient than reading a whole file and returning data all at once?

Comment: Consider why the Java IO package calls many of its classes  a "stream", [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html). Different things follow the stream pattern other than just the stream collection classes.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you don't need to use a Stream to process a file in blocks.

Comment: Thank you I have edited the question

Comment: Are you familiar with `Iterator`s?  They, too, are "wrappers around a data source that allow you to operate with it."  Streams...aren't actually that different.

Comment: I just want to clarify - Stream is a method from the BufferedReader class. I see Iterator is an Interface in the Java.util package. I am familiar with these terms and understand the concepts in a general sense. If you had any comments on differences or key benefits, that would be great to hear!

Comment: You are right - I meant Java 8 Stream - what does the other stream tag refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Files.newBufferedReader("/tmp/foo").lines().map(...)...collect(...);
// or
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader("/tmp/foo");
Stream<String> stream = reader.lines();
Collection<String> result = stream.map(...)...collect(...);
```

Is a convenient way to process a text file using a Stream.

But the work of making it fast/efficient is being done by the `BufferedReader`, not the `Stream`.

Comment: Where is the stream in that code? I see in the API: BufferedReader reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines. - what does that mean in terms of "stream" in the definition?

Comment: I've broken the statement up.

Comment: Are you saying the top part is the exactly same as the bottom part? Or are they different ways or accomplishing the same task?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the same.

Comment: It’s debatable who is responsible for making this efficient; there are a lot of different components involved under the hood. In fact, `BufferedReader` is the reason why it is not fast and efficient, at least in the reference implementation. It’s strongly recommended to use `Files.lines(…)` instead, starting with Java 9, you are likely getting a more efficient result (esp. when using parallel streams).

Comment: @Holger can you explain in a general or basic way how Stream works under the hood

Comment: @don maybe [this article](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-java-streams-3-brian-goetz/) can help you

Comment: @Holger I like the title; I have a feeling you're right that it might be helpful lol